# Uniform convergence with $\sin^n(x)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, uniform-convergence

I have to determinate the uniform convergence (set of convergence) and calculate the sum of this series:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sin^nx \frac{(-1)^{n-1} + n^2}{n}
$$
For the convergence, I applied the definition, but I do not know how to treat the $\sin^n(x)$. Can someone explain me how to do this exercise, please? Thank you!

Comment: Maybe $\lvert \sin x \rvert \leq \lvert x\rvert $ (for every real $x$) could come in handy.

Comment: Let $y = \sin(x)$ to express this as a power series. The domain of convergence can be obtained easily from the ratio test. For those values of $y$ where the series converges, we have the sum of two power series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n} y^n + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n y^n$$both of which can be calculated by standard techniques. As always with power series, the convergence is uniform on any closed interval contained within the radius of convergence.